# azure pipeline not generating bin folder for cproject

Tags: c#, azure-devops

Yaml definition

```
pool:
  name: vjAppPool
  demands: msbuild

variables:
  BuildPlatform: 'Any CPU' --Used for solution
  BuildConfiguration: 'Release'
  BuildPlatform_Proj:'AnyCPU' --Used for csproject

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1


- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build  service project'
  inputs:
    solution: '$/VjTS/Main/vjApp-DEV-3.2.0/Vj.vjApp.Services.Web/Vj.vjApp.Services.Web.csproj'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform_Proj)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArguments: '/t:Restore /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DebugType=full /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
    clean: true

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**/bin/**/*.*'
    SymbolServerType: TeamServices
    SymbolExpirationInDays: 365
    IndexableFileFormats: All
    SymbolsArtifactName: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  continueOnError: true


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

I have service project solution which is containing several project, i need to publish the main project using azure CI and CD so i configured azure build pipeline  but when the artifacts are generated i noticed that there is no bin folder only obj folder created with deployment files. what could be the possible reasons for this behavior?

**Log Build  service project:**

> ##[debug] FileName: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe'
> ##[debug] Arguments: '"C:\AgentPool_work\4\s\Vj.App.Services.Web.csproj" /nologo /nr:false
> /t:"Clean"
> /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\AgentPool_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.231.5\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=C:\AgentPool_work\4\s|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\AgentPool_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.231.5\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
> /t:Restore /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DebugType=full
> /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
> /p:PackageLocation="C:\AgentPool_work\4\a" /p:platform="AnyCPU"
> /p:configuration="Release"
> /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_cfbbcadb-2ff1-4896-b19c-651bf91799fa_build_38_0"'
> ##[debug] RequireExitCodeZero: 'True' "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe"
> "C:\AgentPool_work\4\s\Vj.App.Services.Web.csproj" /nologo /nr:false
> /t:"Clean"
> /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\AgentPool_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.231.5\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=C:\AgentPool_work\4\s|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\AgentPool_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.231.5\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
> /t:Restore /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DebugType=full
> /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
> /p:PackageLocation="C:\AgentPool_work\4\a" /p:platform="AnyCPU"
> /p:configuration="Release"
> /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_cfbbcadb-2ff1-4896-b19c-651bf91799fa_build_38_0"
> Build started 16-01-2024 16:51:57 PM.
>
> Project "C:\AgentPool_work\4\s\Vj.App.Services.Web.csproj" on node 1
> (Clean;Restore target(s)). CoreClean:   Creating directory
> "obj\Release".

Comment: You use `/p:WebPublishMethod=Package`.... why do you expect any folders?

Comment: Hi, can modify the MSBuildarguments solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another publish method like:

```
    msbuildArguments: '/t:WebPublish /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DebugType=full /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem  /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*.sln` file to build instead of the `*.csproj` file in your Build task:

```
solution: '$/VjTS/Main/vjApp-DEV-3.2.0/Vj.vjApp.Services.Web/Vj.vjApp.Services.Web.csproj'
```